# If statements in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to write an if statement to further classify my data by type. Basically the cells currently contain the ID number and tissue type, but i want to figure out a way to insert the tissue type classification into the cell below.

So for example the ID # and tissue type (all in the same excel cell) is written 868686 Skin. And in the cell below, I wrote the formula IF(B2="Skin", "Skin", " ") but because I didn't have the whole contents of the cell (the ID#) included, it didn't find it. So is there a way to say IF B2 *contains* the word skin, then do this...

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `FIND`, this will return the number of the starting position of the text `String` in cell `B2`.

If `123 Skin` was in `B2` then `=FIND("Skin", B2)` would return `5` (Skin starts at the fifth position counting from the left).

Putting together with the IF statement, it would look like:

```
=IF(FIND("Skin", B2) > 0, "Skin", " ")
```

(So if the result > 0 then it has been found in the cell)

You would probably want to take it one step further to take into consideration what happens if the cell doesn't contain that text (if you don't do that it will show an error)

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND("Skin", B2), 0) > 0, "Skin", " ")
```

(Above will return 0 if it hasn't been found)

Comment: I tried that but I got an error #VALUE! Why did you set it greater than 0 __> nevermind I realized it was because this formula is case sensitive

Comment: With the find comment, is it possible to add on an else statement. like if skin is in the cell of interest, write "skin" but if brain is in the cell of interest write "Brain" or if eye is in the cells of interest write "Eye"

Comment: it is with embedded if statements, for example `=IF(first condition, "do this", IF(second condition, "do that", "otherwise do this"))` and so on

Comment: Okay, I tried that and I can't get it to work. Do you see anything wrong with my statement? =IF(FIND("soft tissue",B2),"soft tissue",IF(FIND("central",B2),"Central Nervous System"))

Comment: seems fine, you just need to wrap the finds with iferrors + take into account what happens if neither are found `=IF(IFERROR(FIND("soft tissue",B2),0),"soft tissue",IF(IFERROR(FIND("central",B2),0),"Central Nervous System", "Other"))`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking to use the FIND command.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-FINDB-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628